# MIM sync error in DELTAIMPORT showing server encountered errors

Tags: windows-server, mim

I am trying to configure MIM in production environment, In the lower environments i have not faced any issues. But in production environment i am unable to sync. Please help me solve this issue.

MIM Synchronization Service Manager history showing stopped-server in DELTAIMPORT.

I have checked the event log saying
"The management agent ADMA failed on run profile "FULLIMPORT" because the server encountered errors."

EVENT ID: 6056.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved after updating Sharepoint Databases

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119511)

Comment: upgrade for Sharepoint_config database is pending, After upgarding the database issue was resolved